# Windows 10 firewall settings to receive UDP

Tags: windows, firewall, udp

I have UDP packets sent from a sensor device to a PC running Windows 10. The UDP traffic can be monitored using Wireshark, but only after completely disabling the Windows firewall are the UDP packets picked up by the monitoring software.

Of course I don't want to disable the Windows firewall permanently, so I've tried to add a rule to allow this incoming traffic.

```
Source (sensor):        192.168.178.201:4002
Receiver (Windows PC):  192.168.178.24:4000
```

The new rule I've added allows UDP packets from source 192.168.178.201:4002 to destination 192.168.178.24:4000, but this didn't help. Even if I select any IP address and port the UPD traffic is still blocked.

Maybe there's a higher-ranking rule that prevents the exception to work?

What setting do I need to allow the desired UDP packets?

Comment: We can't tell you if there is a conflicting rule unless you provide the full ruleset. What rule did you add? What other rules are there?

Comment: That's true. The list of rules is seemingly endless. So I rather should ask if there is a way to identify the conflicting rules. Or maybe the new rule could be given the highest priority?
The new rule I've addedd allows UDP packets from source 192.168.178.201:4002 to destination 192.168.178.24:4000.

Comment: Have you tried moving this rule up the list?

Comment: Do you have any _deny_ rules that would block the traffic? The rule order in WF is "all deny rules > all allow rules > default".

Comment: You can enable logging for allowed/denied packets to help explain what it's seeing. Can you add a screenshot of the rule in the "windows defender firewall with advanced security" page? The official precedence rules apply in is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/best-practices-configuring#understand-rule-precedence-for-inbound-rules

Comment: After checking a long list of rules that may conflict with my new rule I've found that there are some seemingly contradictory rules for Zulu Java which is used to display the sensor data.
There is a rule allowing all UDP traffic for all addresses (local and remote) and all ports. There is another rule blocking all UDP traffic for all addresses and all ports. Both rules are activated.
When disabling the blocking rule I can receive sensor data.
But why are there two contradictory rules and how can I move a rule up the list to give it a higher priority? I've just found that I can sort the list

Comment: I've missed one significant difference:
The allowing rule is for private networks, the blocking rule is for public networks. Seemingly I'm using a public network here.
Still it would be good to block all traffic with the exception of my new rule. How can this be achieved?

Comment: According to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc755191(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
the allow rules are executed after the blocking rules. So my new rule allowing UDP packets from the sensor device should overwrite the Zulu Java rule which blocks everything.
However, the linked article is for Windows Server 2008, maybe things have changed with Windows 10.

Comment: Is that existing rule limited to a specific program/service (e.g. zulu.exe)? For those rules, windows will only accept traffic to the port that process is currently listening on, even if the rule says allow all IPs/ports. You may just need to remove the blocking rule, and adjust the allow rule to work on public profile. And no, that article is still correct. Explicit deny rules take precedence

Comment: The best practice is to have only one type of rule: Allow or Deny. Then just set the firewall to Deny/Allow all un-matched traffic at the profile (private/public) level.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if that’s clean and a good solution but this works:

1. Change the Zulu UPD blocking rule to exclude the specific ports.

   So it is not blocking all ports any more but just say 0-3999, 4001-65535 which allows port 4000 for the local port, similar for the remote one.
2. Add a new rule to allow UDP for the specific ports which would be 4000 for the local port.

Both rules are needed to make it work.

Thanks for all the answers that guided me to this solution.